# Windows Class Library vs XNA Class Library

Tags: xna, windows

I'm going to start a library in C# for Navigational Meshes. I would like to use it in both WPF/Winforms and in XNA. Can I create a windows class library and still use it in XNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. They're both just class libraries, the different templates just helps adding some default references.

Also see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256442) and follow the advice in creating both types and running the resulting project files through your favorite diff tool for the details ^^